# What is the meaning of people removing their own eyes in "Event Horizon?"

Tags: horror, event-horizon

I was wondering why people who are affected by the *Event Horizon* tear out their own eyes in some form or another. Sam Neill's character states that where they're going, they *don't need <s>roads</s> eyes*.

When the original captain of the *Event Horizon* sends out a beacon, telling potential rescue crews in pseudo-latin to save themselves, he also is shown to have torn out his eyes, still holding the eyeballs in his hands. So both Sam Neill's character and the original captain do this, but they have wholly different motivations. The former *wants* to go back to "hell", presumably to find his wife. The latter seems to be warning others of it and (presumably) wants to escape.

A literal interpretation of the film raises more questions than it answers. So, I'm wondering if there is an intended meaning to this. I just can't piece it together.

Comment: As an aside I am pretty sure Libera Te Tutemet Ex Inferis is actually Latin.

Comment: @Revenant According to google translate that means: "Payments tutemet from below". Also I think in the film they say "liberate" not "libera".

Comment: yeah I copy pasted from a search result, to be fair I guess it does not really matter one way or another if its real Latin the "translation" was what was important.

Comment: It’s a survival tactic when stranded in deep space. Although the long-term consequences are serious, if you take both eyes out they’ll see you through the week 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That was as bad as it was good!

Answer (score 6):

### Blinding oneself is a uniquely crippling, painful, and grotesque act

Most obviously, having one's eyes gouged out is one of the most painful experiences a person can imagine. To do it *to oneself* implies some extreme motivation.

In myth, Oedipus blinded himself upon discovering that he had unwittingly killed his own father and married his own mother. Let that example serve to illustrate the kind of unthinkable anguish that authors of fiction think might cause someone to do this.

So, one reason *Event Horizon* does this is to signal to viewers how extremely disturbed these characters have become.

The other thing to note is that humans depend on vision more than any of our other senses, and loss of vision is a uniquely crippling injury. Someone who *chooses* to lose their sight must have some stupendously compelling reason, and Event Horizon presents two:

- First, that what's happening in the "hell dimension" is so awful that it is preferable to never see *anything* ever again than to look upon the depravity one more instant.
- Second, that they no longer *require* regular human vision, presumably because they have gained some other, supernatural, sense. This very clearly seems to be the case, since Sam Neill displays no handicap when he fights Laurence Fishburne in the reactor room in the film's finale.<sup>1</sup>

Both captains gouge out their own eyes because they are driven utterly mad. The original captain, in his madness, thinks it's a good idea to blind himself, while Sam Neill does it to reject mortal vision in favor of demonic senses. The former does it out of fear, the latter because he has been totally seduced by demons.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> Notably, during the fight, Sam Neill keeps shouting "do you see?" at Fishburne. IIRC, this is while he's laying out the demons' 'glorious' plans for the crew and all the fresh victims they hope to obtain by the use of the Event Horizon. So, I think "see" has at least a double meaning in this context. It definitely seems significant that a guy who removed his own eyes goes on to impatiently ask whether his opponent can "see."</sup>